# Specific number of records to load on primefaces live scrolling

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

I have a primefaces datatable with live scrolling enabled.The datatable is cell editable,having multiple multiple selection,filtering enabled based on columns.I have assigned the attribute scrollRows to 20.But since it is having more than 50 columns it is taking more time for next set of 20 records to get loaded when i reach the end of scrolling.Is there any way by which initially on page load i load only 50 records and then at the end of scroll i load small number of records say about 5.

My JSF code snippet

```
<p:dataTable id="workSpaceList" var="data"
        value="#{workSpaceBean.lazylpId}" widgetVar="multiSelection"
        selection="#{workSpaceBean.selectedRows}" editable="true"
        resizableColumns="true" editMode="cell" liveScroll="true"
        tableStyle="table-layout:auto; width:1124px;" scrollable="true"
        scrollWidth="1150" scrollHeight="350" scrollRows="20"
        styleClass="datatable" columnClasses="columnwidth"
        filteredValue="#{workSpaceBean.filteredWorkSpaceItems}">
        <p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width:13px">
        .
        .
        .53 columns
        .
        .
```

I have implemented datamodel in the managed bean which is of request scoped.

code snippet of the datamodel class

```
public class WorkSpaceDataModel extends ListDataModel<WorkSpaceItem> implements SelectableDataModel<WorkSpaceItem>{

public WorkSpaceDataModel()
{

}

public WorkSpaceDataModel(List<WorkSpaceItem>data)
{
    super(data);
}                                                                     


@Override
public WorkSpaceItem getRowData(String rowKey) {

    List<WorkSpaceItem>workSpaceItems=(List<WorkSpaceItem>)getWrappedData();

    for(WorkSpaceItem workSpaceItem : workSpaceItems) {

        if(String.valueOf(workSpaceItem.getLpID()).equals(rowKey))
        {
            return workSpaceItem;

        }

    }

    return null;


}

@Override
public Object getRowKey(WorkSpaceItem workSpaceItem) { 
    return workSpaceItem.getLpID();
}
```

}

My customer doesn't want pagination to be implemented :( (the table has more than 4000 records ),so the only option left with me is to go with live scrolling.But because of more than 50 columns it is creating problems with record load times.Please suggest me how i can improve the performance.
Thanks in advance.